# How to fix "500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null" in reacts typescript application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to troubleshoot this error:

[image]

I'm scratching my head because line 60 has no split statement:

```
Line 60: @import 'vars';
```

The only split statement I see is:

```
const components = product.pid.split(URL_COMPONENT_SEPARATOR).filter((x) => x !== product.productId);
```

on line 26 on ProductCard.tsx. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the `pid` field on product not being initialised when the `ProductCard` component is first rendered.

This is usually due to incomplete data being supplied from your back-end, or because your component is rendered prior to or during a network request to fetch data for your component (ie in this case `product`)

Consider a defensive approach for the code you provided to resolve this, like so:

```
const components = typeof product.pid === 'string' ? product.pid.split(URL_COMPONENT_SEPARATOR).filter((x) => x !== product.productId) : [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of faulty source maps, the line number shown on the error message can be off. Refer to Dacre Denny's answer as a defense here.

This error can be seen when a backend (elasticsearch instance in my case) is acting up.